# Node.js https get request ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, https

My question is similar to this question:  [Node Js :is it possible to hit 1000 http get request to some api from a node js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301274/node-js-is-it-possible-to-hit-1000-http-get-request-to-some-api-from-a-node-js) but their solution of throttle did not work for me.

I am making calls to our api/website hosted on Google App Engine to trigger a task to update the memcache for specific product pages.  This function `updateCache` is called from an `async.eachSeries`. The code is pretty straight forward: (this is a sanitized version)

```
function updateCache(object_name, callback) {
  var options = {
    host          : 'www.example.com',
    path          : '/update-cache/' + object_name,
    method        : 'GET',
    agent         : false,
  };
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function() {
      if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('successful');
      }
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('end');
      callback();
    });
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('failed');
    console.error(e.stack);
    callback();
  });
  req.end();
}
```

It runs perfectly on my Mac machine but I need the script to run on a Windows PC using Windows 7 and that is were it gets this error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:552:26)
```

Comment: Did you see this related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/node-js-econnreset

Comment: I implemented an solution I found on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322248/node-js-distinguishing-errors-when-making-http-request). So far my script has been running fine.

Comment: I have still been throwing errors in the `req.on('timeout',...)` so the code I followed was able to catch the error but I still do not know how to fix the timeouts and connections closing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322248/node-js-distinguishing-errors-when-making-http-request) and it looked something like this:

```
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function() {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            // HANDLE
        }
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200 && app.retry_count < 10) {
            app.retry_count += 1;
            retriggerFunction(param, callback);
        } else {
            app.retry_count = 0;
            return callback();
        }
    });
});
req.on('error', function(e) {
    app.retry_count += 1;
    retriggerFunction(param, callback);
});
req.on('timeout', function(e) {
    app.retry_count += 1;
    retriggerFunction(param, callback);
    req.abort();
});
req.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
    app.retry_count += 1;
    retriggerFunction(param, callback);
    req.abort();
});
```

`retriggerFunction` would just be the function that I wrapped this in. It may not be "correct" but it is currently working for me. If anyone has improvements on this please let me know